# Quotient Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a ringed space, and $J$ be a sheaf of ideals of the structure sheaf. Define, $Y = \{x\in X ~ | ~ J_x \not = \mathcal{O}_x\}$, this is a closed set. We have an inclusion $i:Y\to X$. Is there categorical justification that, $i_*i^*(\mathcal{O}/J) = \mathcal{O}/J $?

I really do not want to work with the tedious constructions to justify that.

I know that one has the following exact sequence, 
$$ 0 \to i_!i^*\mathcal{O}/J \to \mathcal{O}/J \to i_*i^*\mathcal{O}/J \to 0 $$

Now check that $F = i_!i^*\mathcal{O}/J$ has zero stalk for every $x\in X$. If $x\not \in Y$, then $F_x = 0$. If $x\in Y$, then $F_x = \mathcal{O}_x/J_x \not = 0$. And this is unforunate as it prevents the natural map $\mathcal{O}/J \to i_*i^*\mathcal{O}/J$ from being an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact sequence is wrong. One has the exact sequence (See *Exc. I.1.19* in Hartshorne)

$$0 \to j_{!}j^* \mathcal O/J \to \mathcal O/J \to i_*i^*\mathcal O/J \to 0,$$

where $i: Y \to X$ is the inclusion of the closed subset and $j: X \setminus Y =: U \to X$ is the inclusion of the open complement.

For $x \in Y$, we have $(j_{!}j^* \mathcal O/J)_x=0$.

For $x \in U$, we have $(j_{!}j^* \mathcal O/J)_x=(j^* \mathcal O/J)_x = (\mathcal O/J)_{j(x)} = (\mathcal O/J)_x=\mathcal O_x/J_x=0$, since $U$ is precisely the locus, where this quotient vanishes.

Hence, we obtain that $\mathcal O/J \to i_*i^*\mathcal O/J$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, mr Moos for a wonderful and to the point answer. I feel a little embarrased that I royally messed up that exact sequence, especially when I did this exercise in Hartshorne a while back. A slightly related question: is my attitude, to avoid specifics, and focus on general categorical properties the superior way of thinking in geometry? i.e. I do not even ask myself what pushforward and pullback are (even though I am comfortable dealing with tedious specifics).

Comment: Dear @Nicolas, no, there is no superior way of thinking in geometry. Sometimes categorical arguments are fine, sometimes you have to get your hands dirty: just try to read anything on resolutions of singularities (especially in positive characteristic) and you will see that categorical arguments don't play  a big role.